# Building Pango Cairo for Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, cairo, pango, pangocairo

I found someone who ported over Pango Cairo for Android NDK ([blog post](http://cananian.livejournal.com/63595.html), [source code](http://dev.laptop.org/git/users/cscott/android-libs/tree/)). However I have not been succesfull in compiling his example project. Has anyone managed to do so and can tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is what I have tried so far:

- **git clone --recursive http://dev.laptop.org/git/users/cscott/android-libs/**
- git couldn't find pixman for some reason, so did **git clone http://cgit.freedesktop.org/pixman/**, and moved to *android-libs/jni/pixman*
- copied contents of *android-libs/jni/* to *android-libs/examples/java-bitmap/jni* (not sure which Android.mk to keep?)
- renamed *java-bitmap/jni/Makefile.devel* to *Makefile*
- edited *java-bitmap/jni/Makefile* as follows: NDK=/cygdrive/f/android-ndk-r8b
  TOOLCHAIN=$(NDK)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin
- tried to run **make** in *java-bitmap/jni*

I am getting the following error:

```
checking for arm-linux-eabi-gcc... arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot /cygdrive/f/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -mfpu=vfp -Wno-psabi -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -g -isystem /cygdrive/f/workspace/java-bitmap/jni/sysroot/include
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/f/workspace/java-bitmap/jni/pixman':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Makefile:133: recipe for target `pixman/config.h' failed
make: *** [pixman/config.h] Error 77
```

Here is a snippet of the config.h

```
configure:3460: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3482: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot /cygdrive/f/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -mfpu=vfp -Wno-psabi -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -g -isystem /cygdrive/f/workspace/java-bitmap/jni/sysroot/include -nostdlib -DPIXMAN_NO_TLS -DWCHAR_MIN=INT_MIN -DWCHAR_MAX=INT_MAX -I/cygdrive/f/workspace/java-bitmap/jni/pixman-extra -I/cygdrive/f/workspace/java-bitmap/jni/sysroot/include -include pixman-elf-fix.h  -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -lc -lgcc -L/cygdrive/f/workspace/java-bitmap/jni/sysroot/lib conftest.c  >&5
cc1.exe: error: pixman-elf-fix.h: No such file or directory
configure:3486: $? = 1
configure:3524: result: no
configure: failed program was:

..

configure:3529: error: in `/cygdrive/f/workspace/java-bitmap/jni/pixman':
configure:3531: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

did you find a solution?

Comment: @EfEs :-D Sorry, never did figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

I got one step further.

Instead of

```
git clone http://cgit.freedesktop.org/pixman/
```

I downloaded with

```
git clone --recursive http://dev.laptop.org/git/users/cscott/android-pixman
```

and copied all files into the empty `jni/pixman` directory. Now the file `pixman-elf-fix.h` is found, but the linker fails with:

> /tmp/cc2XOCMj.o:(.ARM.exidx.text.main+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'.

But that's probably caused by [this same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561481/error-linking-to-libgcc-a-when-cross-compiling-for-android-but-symbols-exists)