# ecc throws linker error

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, linker-errors, ellcc

I've downloaded the ELLCC binaries (Windows, MinGW). I'm trying to assemble and link a single very simple IR file.

For `x86_64-ellcc-windows-gnu`, it works fine. For `armv7-ellcc-linux` (`arm-linux-engeabi`) and any other ARM target, it throws a linker error similar to this:

> "V:\Users\Teo\Downloads\ellcc-x86_64-w64-mingw32-0.1.12\bin/ecc-ld.exe" -n
>   ostdlib "-LV:\Users\Teo\Downloads\ellcc-x86_64-w64-mingw32-0.1.12\bin\..\
>   libecc/lib/arm-linux-engeabi" -m armelf_linux_eabi --build-id --hash-style=gnu -
>   -eh-frame-hdr -o a.out -e *start -Bstatic "V:\Users\Teo\Downloads\ellcc-x86*
>   64-w64-mingw32-0.1.12\bin\..\libecc/lib/arm-linux-engeabi/crt1.o" "V:\Users\
>   \Teo\Downloads\ellcc-x86_64-w64-mingw32-0.1.12\bin\..\libecc/lib/arm-linux-
>   engeabi/crtbegin.o" "C:\Users\Teo\AppData\Local\Temp\Int32Add-42cacb.o" -(
>    -lc -lcompiler-rt -) "V:\Users\Teo\Downloads\ellcc-x86_64-w64-mingw32-0.1.1
>   2\bin\..\libecc/lib/arm-linux-engeabi/crtend.o"
>   C:\Users\Teo\AppData\Local\Temp\Int32Add-42cacb.o:(.ARM.exidx+0x0): **undefined re
>   ference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'**

Having read [another answer on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561481/error-linking-to-libgcc-a-when-cross-compiling-for-android-but-symbols-exists), I suspect that the linking order is wrong and thus the runtime is not being linked correctly.

But how would I fix the linking order - or whatever the problem actually is -, since the linker is invoked by `ecc`? Is there a reason why `ecc` doesn't take care of this automatically (especially since I'm only giving it just one IR file to compile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arm-linux-engeabi, the symbol "__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0" is defined in libc++.a. It looks like you need to add -lc++ to your link command line (before the -lc) or use ecc++ rather than ecc to link your program.

It works for x86_64 because the missing function is ARM specific, of course.